# A finite-dimensional $K$-algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, group-rings

> Let $A$ be a commutative noetherian domain of characteristic $p>0$ and $K$ be its quotient field. Let $G$ be any finite group whose order is divisible by $p$. Is $KG$ a finite-dimensional $K$-algebra?

If this is so, then I could infer that $AG$ is a classical $A$-order in $KG$, because $AG$ is finitely generated as an $A$-module (since $A$ is a noetherian ring) and we have $AG\cdot K=KG$.

I thank anybody helping.

Comment: What definition are you using for an order? I can't recall everything off the top of my head, but doesn't it have to do with the subring being "dense" in the big ring? It's dense in the sense I'm thinking of, but I can't quite interpret your last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By construction, $KG$ has $K$ dimension $|G|$, so yes, it is finite dimensional.

---

The group algebra $KG$ is defined by forming the free $K$-vector space using the elements of $G$ as a basis, and then enforcing the "obvious" multiplication rules to make it into an algebra. Thus if $G$ is finite, $KG$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: With $A$ a commutative domain having quotient field $K$ and $Q$ any f.d. $K$ algebra, a $A$-subalgebra $R$ in $Q$ is called a classical $A$-order in $Q$ if $R$ is f.g. as an $A$-module satisfying $R.K=Q$. Could you please explain to me your answer more explicitly? Thanks!

Comment: @karparvar OK: I have not seen that particular definition before. What I meant by "dense" is that for every $x\in Q\setminus\{0\}$, there exists $r\in R$ such that $rx\in R\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: @karparvar I don't know what else there is to say about the definition of $KG$, but I tried to add more to the solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. So, the information  I gave about the characteristic of $A$ are of no use, right?

Comment: @karparvar in this case, yes.